# How To Submit form with URL with parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

I have a form where I am submitting data into database. There are following field:

FileName
Choose Image
Button

I am calling this form through URL e,g, https://www.w3schools.com

Now how can I hit button with parameter for example if I add paramaters for fields Like
https://www.w3schools.com?id=1&name=abc&age=2

How can do for button and image.

https://www.w3schools.com?id=1&name=abc&age=2&buton=submit&chooseImage=img.png

Nothing Shows

Comment: I am not sure what you want. submitting the form so parameter are in the url? <form action="script.php" methoid="get">...</form>

Comment: You are not calling a form through a URL, You load a page that may have a form OR you call a server process using a GET request from the location bar.
If you have a form, the form needs the action "/someaction" and have fields with names and values  like `<input type="text" name="id" value="1" /><input type="text" name="firstname" value="abc" />` You can then use method POST or GET (default). You CANNOT send an image using GET

Comment: Without at least the form as code in your question its hard to tell what you want.

Comment: You cannot trigger a form submit on a page using a URL to that page. You need a userscript or a server proxy

Answer (score 3):

To have parameters sent through the URL you need your form to be sent with GET method:

```
<form name="someName" action="https://www.w3schools.com" method="get">
...
</form>
```

You cannot sent image via get, but you can send the image name

Comment: and to send an image, POST

Comment: But How I can hit button available in form, with url?

Comment: You can't 'submit' a form on another page. You submit it on your own form to the desired destination marked in the 'action' property of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Below script pass URL with a parameter (form field data).

```js
$('.filterForm').on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData=$(this).serialize();
  var fullUrl = window.location.href;
  var finalUrl = fullUrl+"&"+formData;
  window.location.href = finalUrl;
  alert(finalUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="filterForm" >
<input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can I Hit this submit button with URL with passing parameters?

Comment: Hi I'm not getting correctly what you're trying to tell... can you come again with alternative method

Comment: @Shivasagar OP wants to click and upload an image on someone's page just by clicking a link to that page from somewhere else

Comment: @mplungjan Absolutely...